# Rengine.eval() returns null

Tags: java, r, nullpointerexception, jri

I'm using the JRI package to build an application using the catR package. On my Mac works perfectly, but when I tried on Windows, the function thetaEst always returns null - only this function. Is there any configuration specific for Windows..?

Here is a piece of code:

```
re.eval("ibsize                 <- 38");
re.eval("responses              <- c(" + resp + ")");
re.eval("discrimination         <- sample(1, ibsize, replace=T)");
re.eval("difficulty             <- c(3.64,  2.42,  2.16,  2.42, 1.64, 1.51, 1.16, -0.95, 1.40, -0.90, 0.31, 1.17, 0.63, 1.22, -0.74, -0.71, -0.74, -0.66, -0.79, 0.03, 1.60, 0.26,  -0.15,  1.81, 1.17, 0.50, -0.04, 1.93, 0.97, -0.04, 3.44, 0.23, 0.05, 3.64, 1.47, 2.08, 3.34, 1.00)");
re.eval("guessing               <- sample(0, ibsize, replace=T)");
re.eval("inattention            <- sample(1, ibsize, replace=T)");
re.eval("itemBank               <- cbind(discrimination, difficulty, guessing, inattention)");
REXP theta = re.eval("thetaEst(itemBank, responses, method = \"EAP\", parInt = c(-3.64, 3.64, 99))");
System.out.println("theta = "+ theta.asDouble());
```

I got a NullPointerException on theta.asDouble();

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like theta is null.  You might not have the packages installed/referenced to instantiate the REXP theta variable if you're using the same code that works on your mac.

Comment: you're right, theta is null. but all the packages are installed/referenced because other functions from the same package  works perfectly - like nextItem(), semTheta()...

Comment: Are you sure you are using the thetaEst properly? can you please show the R out put, running it in only in R console?, it seems like i cant activate it.

Comment: Can you also show all of the Java Main class content ? including the re.assign statement?

Answer (score 0):

Check ibize and other integer values

You might need explicitly say it's a integer like this

ibsize                 <- 38L